# Edit an Object of the PostgresSQL Database in Django from Celery Worker

Tags: python, django, database, celery

I'm trying to edit an object which is saved into my Postgress Database used by Django from a Celery Worker.

The Worker is called when the signal `post_save` is called with

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def send_task_creation(sender, instance, created, raw, using, **kwargs):
    print(str(instance.pk))
    rephrase_task.delay(instance.pk)
```

My `task.py` contains the function for the Worker

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery import Celery
from celery_progress.backend import ProgressRecorder
from .models import Task
from time import sleep
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.config_from_object(__name__)

@shared_task(bind=True)
def rephrase_task(self, primary_key):
    print('ID Worker ' + self.request.id)
    Task.objects.filter(pk=primary_key).update(TaskId=str(self.request.id))
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    for i in range(0,100):
        sleep(1)
        i += 1
        progress_recorder.set_progress(i, 100)
    return 1
```

Now, everything seems to work expect the fact that `Task.objects.filter(pk=primary_key).update(TaskId=str(self.request.id))` does really nothing

I'm seeing the Celery task processing correctly but it seems it can't access the database

My Celery settings in settings.py

```
REDIS_HOST = 'localhost' 
REDIS_PORT = '6379' 
BROKER_URL = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0' 
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600} 
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://' + REDIS_HOST + ':' + REDIS_PORT + '/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

How can I access the database from the Celery Worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I needed to re-start the Celery worker as it seems it won't update settings while running